# File operations in Windows 10 Libraries are very slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, windows-libraries

Any file operation (copying, renaming, creating, etc.) in a folder opened via a library (not Downloads, Pictures etc) is very slow, especially in deep nested folders. This happens also in safe mode. What's weird is that if I open the  *exact same folder* via This PC/Documents, the file operations are fast. This is what I did to debug the issue, in order:

1. Removed indexing locations from Indexing Options.
2. Deleted and rebuilt the index.
3. Restarted in Safe Mode.
4. Created a new test folder in This PC\Documents.
5. Created subfolders 5 levels deep inside the test folder.
6. In the last subfolder created a folder containing 10 empty txt files.
7. Made a copy of that folder. It copied instantly.
8. Created a new library.
9. Included the test folder created previously into the library.
10. Opened the last subfolder (via the library)
11. Made another copy of the folder containing the txt files. It copied after a long delay (about 5-6 seconds).

Does anyone know this issue and how to solve it? Or test this on their computer to see if they have the same issue? Thank you.

Comment: Libraries is a concept that did not really take hold and do not exist in a new Windows 10 build. Did you add some folder construct that is taking time?

Comment: @John I see...I think they're useful to display the most commonly used folders nice and clear in the file explorer, like bookmarks. I didn't put anything special in them, it's just that file operations are slower than normal, and much slower than normal the further nested the folders are.